# Public Overloads Sub New(Port As Integer) is obsolete: This method has been deprecated

Tags: vb.net, socket

Estoy empezando en vb.net pero me topo con esto, estoy con sockets ya que en vb6 se usaba el winsock, tengo varios warnings y uno de estos es este...

```
Property Puerto() As Integer
        Get
            Puerto = _puertoDeEscucha
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _puertoDeEscucha = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub InciarEscucha()
        tcpLsn = New TcpListener(Puerto)

        tcpLsn.Start()

        tcpThd = New Thread(AddressOf EsperarConexionCliente)
        tcpThd.Start()
    End Sub
```

El programa corre pero no quiero dejar esos warnings

Comment: que tipo es TcpListener?

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando el constructor con esta firma:

```
Public Sub New (port As Integer)
```

Que como puede verse en [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) está marcado como obsoleto.

Para quitar el warning deberías usar el siguiente constructor:

```
Public Sub New (localaddr As IPAddress, port As Integer)
```

Por ejemplo, de la siguiente manera:

```
tcpLsn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Puerto);
```

De todas maneras `TcpListener` en si mismo es obsoleto, debes usar [`Sockets`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8)